# How does an @ObservedObject refresh the UI if the willSet property sends out the notification of a change right before the ObservableObject changes?

Tags: swiftui

New to swiftUI, just trying to understand hackingwithswift's tutorial for this part - and tried to lookup documentation for `willSet` in swift.org but I feel like I may be misunderstanding how it actually works.

Here's the code (comments are mine):

```
class DelayedUpdater: ObservableObject {
    var value = 0 {
        // call this code right before the object changes, which is what willSet does.
        willSet {
            // this sends the change notification manually so that any views using this value will refresh.
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    init() {
        for i in 1...10 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i)) {
                self.value += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var updater = DelayedUpdater()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Value is: \(updater.value)")
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is if `willSet` and `objectWillChange.send()` send the notification of a change right before the value changes.. I'm assuming this notification reaches the `@ObservedObject` first, and then it refreshes the UI. But my question is when it refreshes the UI, is that refresh before, or after the value changes?? I know it appears as if it is after, however the `willSet` and `objectWillChange.send()` documentation suggests it sends the notification of a change right before a change..

So if that's the case, how does the UI refresh with the newValue, if the refresh occurs before the actual change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the value change and the UI update run on the main queue, and there is only one queue. Before SwiftUI’s task to update the value on the main queue can run, the value will have been updated.

So why send the message before the value is updated? Because that gives SwiftUI the chance to observe the previous value to prepare for any animation. This means that part of SwiftUI is running on another queue, but when it comes time to actually update the value, SwiftUI will schedule a task to run on the main queue, and the value will have been updated at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I understand, so we are essentially telling the UI to pay attention for the next change? and then when it changes, it can do its work to set the value, and then it loses attention to work on other more important things in the task queue rather than continually observing the object for changes? So I presume this approach is more efficient for swiftUI to run things?

Comment: The `objectWillChange.send()` message is essentially "We're changing a value you care about.  Note its current value and prepare to redraw yourself asap."  SwiftUI doesn't have to wait for the value to change, because the first opportunity it gets to draw on the main queue will have the new value.

Comment: A good thing to know is that willSet will always be triggered but view is not rerendering if value is not changed even if you have a function that is setting the value to be same as previous. The reason is that SwiftUI needs to perform diffing between the old state and the new state to decide if a new rendering of the view is necessary.